# Consulta Mysql baseado em resultado de checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Estou com dificuldade em criar uma consulta mysql com base em checkbox.

**1. Tenho um formulário baseado em um select que contém um checkbox por
    linha**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo $linhas['id'];?>" >
```

**2. Eu faço um implode para pegar o "id"**

```
$check_id = implode(',', $_POST["check"]);
```

**3. var_dump do $check_id resulta os "id" que eu quero (clicados)**

```
var_dump($check_id)."<br>"; // retorno do var_dump é string(3) "1,3"
```

**4. por último gostaria de criar uma consulta para exibir os dados com
    base no "id" selecionado.**

```
$comprado = mysqli_query($conn, "

            SELECT pedidos.id as id_comprado, qtde
            FROM pedidos
            WHERE id_comprado = '$check_id'

            ");
```

**5. Estes são os erros exibidos**

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in xxx on line 108

Minha linha 108 é `$comprados = mysqli_num_rows($comprado);`

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in xxx on line 132

Minha linha 132 começa com `while($comprados = mysqli_fetch_array($comprado)){...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resolução do seu problema é simples. Na sua consulta, utilizar `IN` ao invés do `=`. Dessa forma:

```
$comprado = mysqli_query($conn, "
    SELECT pedidos.id as id_comprado, qtde
    FROM pedidos
    WHERE pedidos.id IN (".$check_id.")
");
```

EDIT: editei a consulta, agora ela funcionará. O apelido atribuido no AS não pode ser usado no WHERE.

Comment: realizei a alteração sugerida, porém os erros permanecem. Cheguei a usar o IN anteriormente, com outra estrutura e não tinha conseguido.

Comment: Tente imprimir o valor de $comprado para verificar qual o real erro. Pois os erros das linhas 108 e 132 são provenientes do resultado de $comprado não ter sido válido.

Comment: @HugoBarreto editei minha resposta, agora creio que não falhará.

Comment: Fui tentar fazer direto no sql como vc sugeriu e descobri este erro no where também, funcionou, porém trouxe apenas um resultado. No sql eu fiz da seguinte forma para simular "SELECT id, qtde, situacao FROM pedidos WHERE id IN ('1,2,4')", e o resultado foi que apenas as informações do id "1"... isso ocorreu também alterando a consulta no php.

Comment: @HugoBarreto só retornou um no seu caso pois você colocou `'1,2,4'` entre aspas simples, na verdade vc tem que colocar `('1', '2', '4')` ou `(1,2,4)`. Viu a diferença?

Comment: Perfeito. Erro de principiante rsrs. ao menos fiquei uns 5 dias testando outros códigos/termo que serão úteis em outros problemas. Resolvido!

Comment: @HugoBarreto Caso esta resposta tenha resolvido, o stackoverflow conta com a opção de você marca-la como a correta, para que outras pessoas quando procure pelo mesmo erro tenha em mente que isso lhe ajudou e pode ajudá-las também.

Comment: Eu não estava encontrando esta opção, mas agora acho que foi... vlw e até